# How to use interpret in Language.Haskell.Interpreter?

Tags: haskell

Is interpret used to eval haskell expression ? if so, how can i use it?

```
Language.Haskell.Interpreter> :t interpret 
interpret :: (Data.Typeable.Internal.Typeable a, MonadInterpreter m) =>
String -> a -> m a

>interpret "1+1"
<interactive>:20:1:
Ambiguous type variable `m0' in the constraint:
  (MonadInterpreter m0) arising from a use of `interpret'
Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
In the expression: interpret "1+1"
In an equation for `it': it = interpret "1+1"
```

Regards!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are [some examples here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hint/0.3.1.0/doc/html/Language-Haskell-Interpreter.html#v%3ainterpret):

```
interpret "head [True,False]" (as :: Bool)
interpret "head $ map show [True,False]" infer >>= flip interpret (as :: Bool)
```

where "Convenience functions to be used with interpret to provide witnesses":

```
as :: Typeable a => a   
infer :: Typeable a => a
```

P.S.
API of `Language.Haskell.Interpreter` is not very user-friendly. Without inspecting its example files its usage would be a conundrum for me (not an advanced Haskeller).

But with the help of an example here we go:

```
Prelude> import Language.Haskell.Interpreter as I
Prelude I> runInterpreter $ setImports ["Prelude"] >> interpret "map (*2) [1,2,3]" (as :: [Int])
Right [2,4,6]
```

The helpful example file can be found in `~/.cabal/packages/hackage.haskell.org/hint/0.3.3.5/hint-0.3.3.5.tar.gz`.

It looks like `interpret` must be run inside a monad constrained by `MonadInterpreter m`:

```
Prelude I> :t runInterpreter 
  runInterpreter
  :: (Functor m, Control.Monad.CatchIO.MonadCatchIO m) => 
     InterpreterT m a -> m (Either InterpreterError a)
Prelude I> :t interpret 
  interpret
  :: (Data.Typeable.Internal.Typeable a, MonadInterpreter m) => String -> a -> m a
```

IO clearly does not have an instance for `MonadInterpreter` class, hence the error. This is an expected behaviour, since `IO` monad of GHCI does not have required information about the interpreter session. A proper monad type must be set by `runInterpreter`.

Comment: with this examples i got same errors No instance for (MonadInterpreter m0) arising from a use of `interpret'.
I use ghc 7.6.1

Comment: @shk You need to tell ghc(i) which monad to use. Supposing `IO` has a `MonadInterpreter` instance, `interpret "head [True,False]" (as :: Bool) :: IO Bool` should work.

Comment: > interpret "head [True,False]" (as :: Bool) :: IO Bool   --reports:  No instance for (MonadInterpreter IO) ...

Comment: @z_axis I'm sorry for a short and not exact answer. See the update.